# Framework icons color in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, build

What is the difference between these icons in Linked Frameworks And Libraries tab? Why some of them have default yellow color, and some are whitened?

[image: White Framework Icon and Default Framework Icon]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are the frameworks that Xcode thinks not exists and they will be available after the build process. Sometimes Xcode forgets to update the UI for that and remove the *whitened* tint color.

Answer (score 1):

**Framework icon color**

My observations says that frameworks which are targets of **generated** projects(CocoaPods, Tuist) are whitened(pale).

For example you are able to create a workspace and experiment with this